How do I check if multiple returned class objects have the same value for comparison and edit only one, while keeping both for addition later
I'm currently creating a blackjack card game using OOP and the blessed library. As it stands I create the card objects which return a class object to me:
player_card_data = [<blackjack.card.Card object at 0x7f3900226330>, <blackjack.card.Card object at 0x7f3900225f70>]

I can then dive into those and get the card value:
player_card_data[0].card_value

This, for example, gives me 10.
My current issue is I want to account for aces, which earlier in my program I set to the value 11. I need to check and see what the score is so that the hand does not automatically go bust by drawing 2 aces (22), I'm currently building it into a reusable function and figure I'd need to do a simple compariosn operator.
(This is also currently what I am trying / have tried and so far no results.)
def calculate_score(player_card_data):
  """
  Calculates the score of the players cards, accounting for aces, then returns the score
  """
  if player_card_data[0].card_value == player_card_data[1].card_value:
    player_card_data[0].card_value = 1

  player_score = player_card_data[0].card_value + player_card_data[1].card_value
  return player_score

The problem I see with this while it works with two cards, it doesn't scale and completely breaks if more than 3 cards are in the player_card_data object. I was thinking of using *args but i'm not sure if this would work / have not been able to get it working in this situation. I am not looking to make it into a set as I need both values for addition later in the function.
The card objects are initially populated into a deck array, which the cards are then drawn from, then deleted from this deck. This ensures that the objects i'm manipulating only exist for the round of blackjack being played and as a result won't affect the deck as after the current round, no longer exist. I am aware that manipulating objects is generally bad practice but if the object no longer exists after the round figured it isn't a severe issue.
I do it like this to create a finite number of plays before the deck needs to be "reshuffled" (recreated).
The data that's fed in to create the card objects is housed outside the card class inside objects and arrays:
suits = ["Spades", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds"]
suits_values = {"Spades":"\u2664", "Hearts":"\u2661", "Clubs": "\u2667", "Diamonds": "\u2662"}
cards = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
cards_values = {"A": 11, "2":2, "3":3, "4":4, "5":5, "6":6, "7":7, "8":8, "9":9, "10":10, "J":10, "Q":10, "K":10}

which is then sent to the card class and populated in the deck to make the 52 unique card objects:
def create_deck():
  """
  Creates a new deck of 52 card objects by passing each card suit, card and card value
  into the Card class, then appending it to the deck array.
  """
  # we now create our deck of cards
  deck = []
  # Loop for every type of suit
  for suit in suits:
    cards = ["A", "A", "A", "A"]
    # Loop for every type of card in a suit
    for card in cards:
      # Adding card to the deck
      deck.append(Card(suits_values[suit], card, cards_values[card]))

  return deck

The cards once "drawn" in the round are removed completely from the deck, im looking to find a way to calculate the score based on if the player or CPU draws multiple "Ace" (11) card objects. I do this because I want to draw the cards onto the terminal with blessed later on, so I need to store them in an object to access later.
How could I go about making this scalable for any number of cards?

Even with two cards, your code does the wrong thing for a pair of non-aces. Also, modifying the card objects is probably going to bite you later.

@user2357112 for clarification, and i forgot to update the post with this, the cards objects are initially populated into a deck, which the cards are drawn from, then deleted from this deck. This ensures that the objects i'm manipulating only exist for the round of blackjack being played and as a result won't affect the deck as after the current round, no longer exist.

@mkrieger1 just did! edited the moment after I left the comment!

But yes @user2357112 how would you recommend i fix this function? this is the part i'm stuck on is even though I thought this could work it in fact doesn't.

Why do you want to "edit" card objects if all you want is calculate a score?

@mkrieger1 as stated in the initial post, I want to edit all but one of the objects with a value of 11 to 1 if there's multiple 11's in there. I figured at first just comparing and returning the amount -10 was a good idea but then I ran into the situation of the cpu somehow drawing 3 aces. Which when that happens doesn't work because it's hard coded. So thought that editing all but one of the objects would work

Cards do not have a value outside the context of the game using them. As such, you might consider not storing the value on the card at all, but in a separate mapping (provided by the game) of cards to values.

@chepner hey there, for clarification it does, I have amended the post with how the data is held, the objects are created from that data, so I can then populate them into a card image thats painted to the terminal

No, the problem is that an Ace is not worth 11 points. It is worth 1 or 11 points, as the player chooses, depending on what other cards are in their hand.

@chepner well for simplicity reasons Im enforcing a rule that if the total number would go over 21 because of multiple aces, automatically re-evaluate the second ace to 1. Not quite player choice but solves the problem. On that note this has actually given me an epiphany. Why should I check the object and try to change it. i could just loop over the player data for every ace. Add that value to an array and run a check to see if 11 is already in the array, if it is and the value currently being evaluated is also 11, well change that value to 1 instead. Gonna test it now!

Precisely: an ace's value is determined in the context of evaluating the entire hand, not just the card itself.

An alternative approach is to consider every ace as having value 1, and if the sum of a hand containing at least one ace is 11 or less, add a bonus of 10. This works because at most one of the aces can be assigned a value of 11 without exceeding 21.

Yeah along the lines of what I was thinking so looking to give it a shot if i get time to once the game logic is complete

Final Edit:
Found an answer to the problem, thanks to the comments for helping me course correct on where I was looking. Instead of trying to manipulate the objects to get the data, which even if it's being removed still is mutating data which is always bad practice I settled for this instead.
def calculate_score(player_card_data):
  """
  Function that loops over the player_card_data and adds the score to a score 
  array the function also accounts for multiple aces placed into the array by 
  checking if there is already 11 in the array.
  """
  player_score = []
  for i in player_card_data:
    if 11 in player_score:
      player_score.append(1)
    else: 
      player_score.append(i.card_value)
    Sum = sum(player_score)
  return Sum

This will always check to see if an "Ace" (11) is present in the array and if one is, just append a 1 to the array instead.

This doesn't account for hands where none of the aces should be valued as 11. Consider hitting on AA2 and getting a 10.

@chepner i realize that yes, however for the simplicity of the project and quite frankly as everything I am doing here is unknowns to me, I opted to set it up with the most basic rules in mind. that being aces are calculated at every ace after the first is calculated at being 1. I have however noted this as a fix I want to add if I get time and have an idea of how to do it. But still unsure. If you have an idea of how to though am all ears. As i said before complete python newbie so my knowledge is non existent :) Edit: Just saw your answer actually, and yes that's the idea im working around
